# Convert local image blob to base64, in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, base64, filereader

I'm working on an (HTML) form for an internal tool. Users can fill data out about an issue and attach screenshots. This form is then submitted via ajax to PHPMailer to be sent. The issue is with the screenshots. Due to system limitations I'm unable to have the users actually upload the files to the server.

Currently, I'm using HTML5 filereader to select the files. I then convert the image blobs to base64 and send them to PHPMailer, to be converted to attachments. This is actually working great. However, I'm running into file size issues. Specifically a 1000px x 1000px (402KB) test image. The resulting base64 string is over a million characters long and the request is returning **413 (Request Entity Too Large)**.

I understand that base64 is not an efficient method for transferring large images and I've seen various posts about retrieving / converting image blobs from a database. What I haven't been able to find is info on retrieving a local image blob and converting it to base64.

My image blob URLs look like this:
blob:http://example.com/18960927-e220-4417-93a4-edb608e5b8b3

Is it possible to grab this local image data in PHP and then convert it to base64?

I cannot post much of the source but, the following will give you an idea of how I am using filereader

```
window.onload=function(){
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
    fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
    fileList = document.getElementById("fileList");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);
}

function handleFiles(files) {
  if (!files.length) {
    fileList.innerHTML = "<p>No files selected!</p>";
  } else {
    fileList.innerHTML = "";
    var list = document.createElement("ul");
    fileList.appendChild(list);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if(files[i].size > 1000000) {
            alert(files[i].name + ' is too big. Please resize it and try again.');
        } else {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
      list.appendChild(li);

      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
      img.height = 60;
      img.setAttribute("class", "shotzPrev");
      img.onload = function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
      }
      li.appendChild(img);
      var info = document.createElement("span");
      info.innerHTML = files[i].name + "<br>" + files[i].size + " bytes";
      li.appendChild(info);

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ambulance at the bottom of the cliff codding - cant you change "system limitations"

Comment: _"The resulting base64 string is over a million characters long and the request is returning 413 (Request Entity Too Large)"_ , _"Is it possible to grab this local image data in PHP and then convert it to base64?"_ How would the latter resolve issue if the former is not changed? What do you mean by "grab the local image"? Why do you send `data URI` to server, and not `File` object itself or `FormData` object?

Comment: @guest271314 What I mean is can I transfer the much smaller image blob to PHPMailer and grab the base64 there? Rather than having to transmit that data.

Comment: Yes, you can `POST` the `File` or `Blob` object to `php` without converting the `File` or `Blob` object to a `data URI`. At `php` you can use `php://input` to get the uploaded file

Comment: @guest271314 But can PHP read that local blob URL? When I've tried file_get_contents on those URLs it can't find the file.

Comment: No `php` cannot read the `Blob URL`. You can `POST` the `File` object itself to `php`

Comment: @guest271314 How do I post the file object?

Comment: You can use `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()` to `POST` `File` object to server

Answer (score 1):

You can `POST` the `File` object to `php`

```
fetch("/path/to/server", {
  method: "POST"
  body: files[i]
})
.then(response => console.log(response.ok))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: So, I'm testing this and it's posting the file objects right after they upload. How do I get it to wait, until the form is submitted? So all the data (user text and image objects) can be submitted at once. And then, in my form mailer, I can use `php://input` to access the image object and convert it to base64?

Comment: You can use `FormData` to `POST` multiple key, value pairs to server.

Comment: I understand that I can post multiple values. How do I make it wait until all of the form data is submitted? Sending them to the PHPMailer script right away (before the final form submission) doesn't make much sense, since it needs the rest of the data to send the actual email.

Comment: You can set `required` attribute at the `<form>` elements where input is required by user to submit the `form`

Answer (score 0):

I think its nginx error, please change the **client_max_body_size** value in nginx.conf file.

for example :

```
# set client body size to 2M #
client_max_body_size 2M;
```

PHP configuration (optional)

Your php installation also put limits on upload file size. Edit php.ini and set the following directives.

```
;This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate
memory_limit = 32M

;The maximum size of an uploaded file.
upload_max_filesize = 2M

;Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 3M
```